# FPDF image directory change

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, laravel-5.4, fpdf

Can anyone please help me to change the directory of image in fpdf?

I needed to fetch the image from database where it is saved as my customer has given me the image. I am using laravel 5.4.

```
****
But FPDF is searching for image in fpdf folder.
I want to change directory to the saved folder.
```

//Fetching logo from database

```
$pdf->Image($company->logo,'10','10','30','30');
```

//Directories where the image is saved

```
Image are saved in = (public/upload/logos [folder])
```

Comment: How about you post your code that is related to adding an image to the pdf?

Comment: Sure
I haven't changed a bit in fpdf.php ! Have you worked with fpdf.php before?

Comment: What is the value of `$company->logo`?

Comment: This is an image(jpg) file.

Comment: What does `var_dump($company->logo)` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs the answer of changing the directory of image file to fetch it for laravel in fpdf !

```
    $path = public_path() . '/upload/logos/';

    $filepath = $path . $company->logo;

    if(file_exists($filepath)) {
        $pdf->Image($filepath,'10','10','30','30');
    }
```